# Shipping Labels for UPS, USPS, FedEx

Tags: shipping

Is it possible to get shipping labels for orders?

I would like for people fulfilling orders using the backend to be able to print a shipping label for the order.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention whether you're using an ecommerce add on (eg. [Store](https://exp-resso.com/) or [Cart Throb](http://cartthrob.com/)). If you're using Cart Throb, [CT Admin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ct-admin) has a built in generic packing list that you might be able to customise around the requirements of your chosen shipping companies. I'm not so familiar with the options within Store.

For something pretty quick and simple, you could create a basic order manager outside of the EE control panel and limit access to your required admin member group(s). You could then output the details you require into a template and use a print stylesheet based around your labels. So you could output a simple table to list your order numbers and customer names, with a link to your label template.

If you needed anything more involved, or wanted to integrate with your ecommerce add-on, then I think you'd have to look at building a custom module.